# angular 4 universal - include module if browser

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

So a few of the packages I'm using don't work on universal. I was wondering if there was a way where we could only load specific modules if we are on server.

Currently according the [official repo](https://github.com/angular/universal) you can check if you are in browser or server inside a component using this technique:

```
constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { ... }

...
if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {...}
```

However, if I could check whether currently we are in browser or server via some sort of global variable, selecting which module to load would become trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it if you have separate app.module.
Usually there is a browser-app.module and a server-app.module
and then just include your module under imports.

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    HttpModule,

Comment: there is an app-module for everything and a server app module but not a browser module